# Rails - how to query has_many from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scheduleevent model. The model uses ice_cube to create recurrence rules. A scheduleevent has_many schedtimeranges. A schedtimnerange has a start_time, end_time and booleans for the days of the week Sunday - Saturday. Whatever days are checked are true.

What I need to do is get those days in an array to pass them into ice_cube. How would I join scheduleevent to schedtimeranges, and get Sunday - Saturday where the value is true in a rails model? Do I query the records in the controller, then loop them in the model, or if I need to loop in the model, query them from the model?

Trying to do something like this, but getting a no method schedtimeranges error:

```
  def self.timeranges
    Schedtimeranges.where(scheduleevent_id: self.id).columns.select{ |c| c.type == :boolean }.map(&:name)
  end
  weekdays = self.timeranges
```

Scheduleevent Model:

```
  has_many :schedtimeranges, inverse_of: :scheduleevent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedtimeranges, allow_destroy: true
```

EDIT:

```
weekdays = schedtimeranges.where(scheduleevent_id: id).columns.select{ |c| c.type == :boolean }.map(&:name).to_a
```

This works, but I just need to only get them where the value is true. How do I add that to this? So if a scheduleevent has say 3 schedtimeranges, I want to get the days of week, and start_time/end_time where they are true.

Expected output would be 07:00 AM, 14:00 PM, Monday, Thursday, Friday. (If those are the 3 days that are true.

```
  create_table "schedtimeranges", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "scheduleevent_id", null: false
    t.string "start_time"
    t.string "end_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "monday"
    t.boolean "tuesday"
    t.boolean "wednesday"
    t.boolean "thursday"
    t.boolean "friday"
    t.boolean "saturday"
    t.boolean "sunday"
    t.index ["scheduleevent_id"], name: "index_schedtimeranges_on_scheduleevent_id"
  end
```

EDIT 2:

This is how I am trying to create the recurrence rules. How would I loop the to_ice_cube and pass the scheduleevent_id through?

```
schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new(start)
case orule  
when 'daily'
  schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.daily(1).until(end_date.to_time)    
when 'weekly'
  self.map(&:to_ice_cube).where(scheduleevent_id: self.id).each do |days|
    schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.weekly(1).day(days.map{|s| s.to_sym}).until(end_date.to_time) 
  end
end
```

The idea being that if it is a daily repeat type I just have a start time and end time between all days froms tart date to end date. If it is a weekly recurrence I want to create the rules for the times on those particular days.

I am getting an undefined method map the scheduleevent record.

Comment: Please include the models, schema and example of the data and the expected output. Its very difficult to try to reverse engineer that out of your attempted solution as it has nothing to do with how you would actually solve the problem. You're also not even using the assocation here which you would do with `self.schedtimeranges`.

Comment: Updated my post with more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made it sound way more complicated than it is. Expected output helped a lot. I've added a couple of methods to `Schedtimerange` to make it simpler:

```rb
# why not ScheduleTimeRange and ScheduleEvent

class Schedtimerange < ApplicationRecord
  # sometimes you just have to type all the attributes that you need
  def days
    {
      monday:    monday,
      tuesday:   tuesday,
      wednesday: wednesday,
      thursday:  thursday,
      friday:    friday,
      saturday:  saturday,
      sunday:    sunday
    }
  end

  # # or like this
  # DAYS = %w[monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday].freeze
  # def days
  #   attributes.slice(*DAYS)
  # end

  # desired format goes here
  def to_ice_cube
    [start_time, end_time, *days.compact_blank.keys]
  end
end
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-compact_blank-21*

```rb
>> Schedtimerange.first.to_ice_cube
=> ["07:00 AM", "08:00 AM", :monday, :friday]

>> Schedtimerange.where(scheduleevent_id: 1).map(&:to_ice_cube)
=> [["07:00 AM", "08:00 AM", :monday, :friday], ["11:00 AM", "04:00 PM", :monday, :tuesday]]
```

---

Do the same for `Scheduleevent` if you want:

```rb
class Scheduleevent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :schedtimeranges

  def to_ice_cube
    [id, schedtimeranges.map(&:to_ice_cube)]
  end
end
```

```rb
>> Scheduleevent.limit(2).map(&:to_ice_cube)
=> [[1, [["07:00 AM", "08:00 AM", :monday, :friday], ["11:00 AM", "04:00 PM", :monday, :tuesday]]],
    [2, [[nil, nil, :monday, :tuesday], [nil, nil, :tuesday, :wednesday]]]]
```

---

If you're calling it from `Scheduleevent`, just use association to get relevant ranges:

```
schedtimeranges.map(&:to_ice_cube).each do |days|
  schedule.add_recurrence_rule IceCube::Rule.weekly(1).day(days).until(end_date.to_time) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! compact_blank definitely sounds like what I was missing. One more question. How would I call this from scheduleevents and pass the scheduleevent_id through? I have updated my OP with additional details on the ice_cube rule I am trying to loop.

Comment: @spacerobot updated. i'm not sure where you're trying to pass `scheduleevent_id`, if you call `schedtimeranges` you're already getting related ranges that belong to current `Scheduleevent`.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize that! It's working now. Thanks so much for the help. This has been some great information for learning!