# Rails - how to reference array positions in output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to output an array in a certain way. Here is the method that gets the data:

```rb
def days
  {
    monday:    monday,
    tuesday:   tuesday,
    wednesday: wednesday,
    thursday:  thursday,
    friday:    friday,
    saturday:  saturday,
    sunday:    sunday
  }
end

def to_ice_cube_time
  [start_time, end_time, *days.compact_blank.keys]
end
```

The output of this is like this:

```
[["6:00 AM", "8:00 AM", :monday, :tuesday], ["9:00 AM", "6:00 PM", :thursday, :friday], ["8:00 AM", "4:00 PM", :monday, :tuesday]]
```

I am trying to loop this in the view and output the correct times on the correct days of the week. Struggling to get the individual values though.

```
<% scheduleevent.to_ice_cube_time.each do |timerange| %>
   <p><%= timerange.start_time %> - <%= timerange.end_time %> </p>
<% end %>
```

That is how I would like to do it, but I get an error

```bash
undefined method 'start_time' for [["6:00 AM", "8:00 AM", :monday, :tuesday], 
["9:00 AM", "6:00 PM", :thursday, :friday], ["8:00 AM", 
"4:00 PM", :monday, :tuesday]]:Array
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
I would look at making a helper method for displaying the data you want in the format you want like this:

```
#schedule_events_helper.rb

def time_slots(day)
  Scheduleevent.joins(:schedtimeranges).where(day => true).order(:start_time).pluck(:start_time, :end_time)
end
```

Then in your view you can do something like:

```
<% %w(:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday).each do |day|
  <%= day.to_s.titleize %>
  <br>
  <% time_slots(day).each do |slot| %>  
    <%= slot[0] %> - <%= slot[1] %>
    <br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This keeps it very obvious what you are doing to get the data and how it is being manipulated to get it to the desired format.

*** older answer below, either should work ***

You are trying to use an ActiveRecord method on an array. Arrays are referenced by their index, which starts at zero moving left to right. You could do:

```
<% scheduleevent.to_ice_cube_time.each do |timerange| %>
 <p><%= timerange[0] %> - <%= timerange[1] %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Per your comment that this references a previous answer you should include that link in your question and explain that. I still think you should rework the original query to get the data in the format you want rather than all of these twists and turns. As soon as things are put into an array format you loose a lot of the obvious data meaning. You want a hash output like

```
{monday: [["6:00 AM", "8:00 AM"], ["8:00 AM", "4:00 PM"]], tuesday: [["4:00 AM", "8:00 AM"], ["6:00 AM", "4:00 PM"]]...}
```

Given your previous post:

```
days_of_week = %w(:monday, :tuesday, :wednesday, :thursday, :friday, :saturday, :sunday)

output = {}
days_of_week.each do |day|
  output[day] = Scheduleevent.joins(:schedtimeranges).where(day => true).order(:start_time).pluck(:start_time, :end_time)
end
```

this should give you an output of

```
{monday: [['6:00 AM', '11:00 AM'], ['8:00 AM', '4:00 PM']...],
 tuesday: [['4:00 AM', '11:00 AM'], ['8:00 AM', '4:00 PM']...],
 ...}
```

And easily represented as: #note I changed this to a simpler form

```
  <% output.each do |day,times| %>
     <%= day.to_s.titleize %>
     <br>
     <% times.each do |slot| %>
       <%= slot[0] %> -  <%= slot[1] %>
       <br>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Think about how you want the final data structured and try to make the code produce that as simply as possible. There are many other ways to tweak by writing instance methods or helper methods to format the output of the data.

Comment: Thanks. So when I do the above this is what is output. ["6:00 AM", "8:00 AM", :monday, :tuesday] - ["9:00 AM", "6:00 PM", :thursday, :friday]. What I am looking to get is 600AM - 8:00AM. How would I reference that first slot of the first item of the array is what I am looking for I think? Yes if it is a Monday I want to see 600 AM - 8:00AM then 8:00AM - 4:00PM under that as Monday has those time ranges. (don't worry about the sensibility of the actual times. It is just test data.

Comment: So: Monday 
         600 AM - 8:00AM
         8:00AM - 4:00PM 
      <br>Tuesday
         600 AM - 8:00AM
         8:00AM - 4:00PM 
....
Is that the structure you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Well you can certainly do it with some contortions of the array of arrays. But that would be terrible code. If you are using Rails I would recommend adding a simple explanation of your data schema and the actual query used to get the data. I think you need a better query that will give you the data in the format you want. But you don't show us any of your schema or query.

Comment: Thanks this is a continuation from a previous post. I think I am close! This is the last little bit I need, but this link shows the schema and a bit more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74883198/rails-how-to-query-has-many-from-model/74905857?noredirect=1#comment132193933_74905857

Comment: Got it! Thnks for the help. Here is the final helper method.   Scheduleevent.joins(:schedtimeranges.where(:schedtimeranges => {day => true}).order(:start_time).pluck("schedtimeranges.start_time", "schedtimeranges.end_time")

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is because you are trying to access a position of an array as if it where a method.

Either you just print out `timerange[0]`

or you make your `to_ice_cube_time` method return a `Hash` so you can read it like `timerage[:start_time]`

Or even, you could use the [Hashie](https://github.com/hashie/hashie) gem to wrap it and read it like it is.

If you are using the new Ruby syntax it would look like this

```
def to_ice_cube_time
  Hashie::Mash.new({ start_time:, end_time:, days: *days.compact_blank.keys })
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying Hashie but getting a syntax error with the above. syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting literal content or terminator or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR ... " That is using this: Hashie::Mash.new {start_time:, end_time:, days: *days.compact_blank.keys}

Comment: If not familiar with the error, but maybe your ruby version doesn't allow that syntax. You could try using `start_time: start_time` and so forth.

Comment: Thanks. Playing around with it but getting syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'. I am using Ruby 3.1.2 and Rails 7.0.4.

Comment: Great, so its not that call. I always forget to surround the hash with parenthesis. We have to clearly define that we want to convert a hash into a Mash and not that the hash is a set of parameters to the Mash. Use parenthesis and you'll be set.

Comment: hahah thanks. Still not quite there. With parenthesis I am getting syntax error, unexpected *, expecting '}' Do I need to include anything for Hashie in the model?

Comment: I'm not sure you do, but maybe it depends on your code specifics, maybe removing the asterisk? Try tinkering a little bit by yourself and you'll get it, and then let me know what was it